# How To Copy the Value From Binding Variable To Iterator in adf?

Tags: oracle-adf

i have an adf table that contain many columns + plus a column that have a button , which will open a popup to insert a value

```
<af:table value="#{bindings.BpmCrMilestoneUPView1.collectionModel}" var="row" rows="#{bindings.BpmCrMilestoneUPView1.rangeSize}" >
                <af:column id="c49" headerText="#{bindings.BpmCrMilestoneUPView1.hints.MilestoneSeq.label}" width="50" displayIndex="-1" minimumWidth="12">
                  <af:inputText value="#{row.bindings.MilestoneSeq.inputValue}" readOnly="true" id="it16">
 </af:inputText>
    </af:column>
                  <af:column>
                <af:inputText value="#{row.bindings.Oldmilesseq.inputValue}"  id="it15">
                </af:column>

    <af:column label="openPopUp" >

    <af:button  action = "#{pageFlowScope.CRInitaitiveBean.openCommentsPopUp}" >
     </af:button>
    </af:column>
    <af:table>
```

and this is the popup that contain the input text Field

```
    <af:popup  binding="#{pageFlowScope.CRInitaitiveBean.commentsPopUp}" id="p2">


    <div class="form-group" id="d7">
        <af:outputLabel value="#{lang.previous_comments}" />
        <af:inputText  autoSubmit="true" simple="true" 
        value="#{bindings.newCommentValue.inputValue}" />


   </div>
   </div>
```

and the newCommentValue  pointing to the BpmCrOutputUPView1Iterator in the bindings tab.
if i open the popup for each row , and type values , all values are saved correctly

but when i try to loop the iterator programmatically , the typed values are null

and this is the code

```
         RowSetIterator itr = ADFUtils.findIterator("BpmCrOutputUPView1Iterator").getRowSetIterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Row row = itr.next();
            if (row != null) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Current OUTPUT Row Is Not Null");
                String newComment = (String) row.getAttribute("newCommentValue");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("new Comment is  -------------------> "+newComment); // it should print the typed value for that row

                but it's printed null
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be easier for this specific use case to use the highly recommended *JSFUtils* open source class ***resolveExpression*** function.

JSFUtils and ADFUtils are two utilitary java class made by 3 ADF heroes Duncan Mills, Steve Muench and Ric Smith. You can easily find those using your favorite search engine.

Once added to your project you can **get the value of an EL Expression inside your Java bean** as follow :

```
String newCommentValue= (String)JSFUtils.resolveExpression("#{bindings.newCommentValue.inputValue}");
```

Here is the JSFUtils function for your information :

```
/**
 * Method for taking a reference to a JSF binding expression and returning
 * the matching object (or creating it).
 * @param expression EL expression
 * @return Managed object
 */
public static Object resolveExpression(String expression) {
    FacesContext facesContext = getFacesContext();
    Application app = facesContext.getApplication();
    ExpressionFactory elFactory = app.getExpressionFactory();
    ELContext elContext = facesContext.getELContext();
    ValueExpression valueExp = elFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, expression, Object.class);
    return valueExp.getValue(elContext);
}
```

Comment: But will this experssion get the value typed for each row ??

Comment: If it's something like #{row.bindings.Oldmilesseq.inputValue} it will get the value of the current row. (where the button is)